# 3ds max gold cold foil on product render

Tags: autodesk, 3dsmax

I need advice on how to proceed. I have an object in 3DS max on which an image with "text" should be "pasted". And some parts of this text should be golden (reflective) as I should proceed so that I can edit a given part of the text in 3ds max.

Well thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please update your question to indicate what you have tried and what the result was.  A little clarification can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best go here should be adding a texture! Adding a reflection map would very much help seeing the metal aspect of the gold where you want to!

Comment: How to select the text (which should be gold) from the image

Comment: That should be done in an image editor! 
With uvmap you can position the texture containing your text correclty on your model. After this, applying a material would make you able to add a diffuse (colors), a reflection map (the whiter, the more it reflects) and the refraction map, which blurs the reflected light.
You really should see material and texture tutorials for 3ds max on youtube